# Capture address using HTML5 Geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this working code which is capturing a visitor's current location so I want it to display the visitor's current address into a textbox once the visitor accept to share the location

```
<div>
                    <input id="address"  type="text" style="width:600px;"/>
            </div>
             <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      var map, infoWindow;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -13.961800, lng: 33.7693036},
          zoom: 15
        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }

      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY API KEY HERE]&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do so, you need to use another API of Google which is called Geocoding.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?hl=fr

Indeed, you'll only retrieve GPS Coords with the geolocation API which is just 2 numbers.
Thanks to reverse geocoding, you can retrieve physical adress of the user with the coords X & Y.

Hope it'll help you out !

Comment: I alredy have the geolocation api and its enabled but the problem is the souce code now the one on top how to get the address and put it in the textbox

Comment: if u can edit my code above i will geatly appreciate